# Update attribute with ajax and drug&drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

In my admin pannel i want to create drag&drop fields to update some attribute in database.
for example

i have jquery which allow me to drop user to another table column

after i drop user to this column, i want to update attribute in database using $.ajax put method

Problem:

I dont know how to call my put method

I'm not shure that this way to figure out this issue is correct.

```
  $(".user").draggable({ 
      }
  });
  $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").droppable({
    accept: ".user",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
       var url = ui.draggable.attr('data'); // taking the url which specified in the view

       here should be some $.ajax action

      }// end of drop 
  });
```

and controller

```
  def make_an_admin
    @user.find(params[:id]
    @user.update_attribute(:admin, "true")
  end
```

route

```
put "make_an_admin/:id", to: 'users#make_an_admin'
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try:

```
$.ajax(url, function(){
   type: 'put',
   dataType: 'script',
   data:
     your_optionnal_data: your_optionnal_data_value
   success: function (data) { alert('it works'); }
});
```

url should be something like '/users/make_an_admin/id'.